# How do I ask Siri to tell me what my next Outlook appointment is (just MacBook/MacOS solution, no iPhone)

Tags: ms-office, siri

On my company laptop, all my meetings are in Outlook. How do I ask Siri to tell me what my next Outlook appointment is?

I have no iPhone and using the Apple Calendar app is not an option. (because company information can not be put into apps not authorized for that; in addition, iCloud sync is disabled; simply no Apple)

MacOS version: Monterey 12.0.1 (but assume latest; for posterity)

Assume latest version of outlook (Nov 2021: 16.55)

Comment: When I ask Siri about my Outlook appointments on Outlook it says I have none on the following three months, despite having added some to test. I'll report if I have any luck. Apple Calendar is not an option because it is disabled? You can– probably –have it mirror your Outlook calendar without actually using or replacing it.

Answer (score -1):

This very basic task is not possible to do with Siri.